# HTTPWebRequest Wakes Up WIFI?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, wifi, backgroundworker

I have a rather simple question.

We use BackgroundAgents( [Periodic agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) ) to perform some background tasks which require WiFi(Internet) connectivity in order to perform an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). As mention in the second reference HttpWebRequest is supported but the problem is that if the Windows Phone is locked or idle for more than 1 minute the WiFi is disabled.

I have two important questions based on what I have read and tried until know:

1. Does Microsoft periodically enables WiFi according to predefined intervals to check for new emails or other notifications? If the answer is yes will my background agent rescheduled and run during this interval?
2. Until know I found that HttpWebRequest does not wakes the phone if locked or if is idle for more than 1 minute. Is that the case? A lot of people state that HttpWebRequest works fine if the phone is locked or if the 1 minutes has passed. I was not able to do that.

Thanks.

Sample Code:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {            
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

        MakeHttpRequest("test");
    }
private void MakeHttpRequest(string position)
    {
        if (position != null)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            new Uri("http://mydomain.com/Testing/Details/"+position));
            request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                    }));
                }
            }, request);
        }
        this.NotifyComplete();
    }
```

PS: Please keep in mind that when I run this code while the application is connected to the computer using a USB cable everything runs fine. That's why I believe its a problem with the background worker which does not wake the phone + WiFi in order to perform tha HttpWebRequest.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ?

Comment: Thanks @Yahia. Added the source code!

Comment: Which BackgroundAgent class are you using?

Comment: @Salamis - You mean `PeriodicTask`?

Comment: Yes. I use PeriodicTask Agent.

Comment: @salamis thanks for the source... please provide much more details... like: how much memory/RAM does the device have ? how long and how often does the task run ? Is the device connected to GSM/CDMA too or just via WiFi?

Comment: @Yahia The device is the following http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_e900_optimus_7-3532.php. The task is set to run every 120 seconds using the LaunchForTest() method and the device is only connected to WiFi without a SIM card.

Comment: @salamis how long does the task run ?

Comment: The task runs for about 5-6 seconds but I do not believe that is an error with time or PeriodicTask because it is working just fine if the device is connected using USB (never in idle state). If the device is connected through WiFi, WP7,5 disconnects WiFi after about one minute of being idle and the device screen is locked. Do the PeriodicTask and the HttpWebRequest suppose to enable WiFi in order to perform the HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my experience with using the phone on a day-to-day basis that Windows Phone does not reenable wifi after it locks unless the phone is plugged in and charging. It also allows data transfers that were already started to complete before disabling the wifi.

However, even if the phone tried to reconnect periodically, some wifi providers redirect to an authentication page for authentication every time the user reconnects and Windows Phone does not handle that situation.

In reality, there's no guarantee that you have data services available as the user walks around with the phone, so handling the issue should be part of a normal path for the application code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if the phone tries to periodically reconnect?

Comment: @salamis - I don't believe it does. I can't find any documentation to that effect, but there is anecdotal evidence from apphub and phone support forums (if you google). Its also been my experience that it does not try to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the only solution is to handle the issue as part of the code. and only execute the background worker if network is available. Even if it is WiFi, 3G, 3.5G or whatever. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @salamis - Yes, that's the best choice.